# How to replace nth character in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to replace the nth character in SQL Server. I tried with it using `replace()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(ABC,0,1)  FROM XXX
```

In above code all zeros will be replaced with one, but I only want to change it in a particular position and sometimes that position can change.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

use stuff 
The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a specified length of characters in the first string at the start position and then inserts the second string into the first string at the start position.

```
select STUFF(ABC, starting_index, 1, 'X') from XXX
```

"Here your int position to replace" is the position no just replace with any int no and that position will be replaced
**Note :** (Thanks to [pcnate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3851647/pcnate) for suggestion)
starting_index is your int position to replace.

Comment: I recommend using a fake variable name such as `lenth_ofthestring_to_replace_from_starting_index` or `starting_index` to clearly indicate that it should be a number and not a string. Having an entire sentence to describe a string just bloats an answer

Answer (score 31):

You're looking for [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
select STUFF(ABC, @n, 1, 'X') from XXX
```

This would replace the `@n`th character with an `X`.

*Technically it seeks into the original string at column `ABC` starting at position `@n`, deletes `1` character, then inserts the string `'X'` at that position.*

Answer (score 13):

You use [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql) for this:

```
SELECT STUFF(ABC, 5, 1, '1')
FROM XXX
```

This would replace the 5th character with a 1.

Answer (score 8):

Use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(abc, 0, 1, 'a')
```

It is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

Comment: It also work with variables :
`SET @MY_VARIABLE=STUFF(@MY_VARIABLE,14,1,'h');`

Answer (score 6):

Use Stuff.

```
STUFF(Column_Name,starting_index,
lenth_ofthestring_to_replace_from_starting_index, character_to_replce)
```

Example_

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100) = '123456789'
select @str
SELECT STUFF(@str,2,1, 'hello') 
-- want to replece 1 charter starting from 2nd position with the string 'hello'
```

Check this.

```
 SELECT STUFF(@str,2,25, 'hello'),len(@str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a table with a `PartDesc` column, as below, where I need to delete the characters starting from index 1 until the `-` character.

| PartDesc |
| --- |
| OPERA_BLUE-ALTROZ DCA XZ 1.2 RTN BS6 |
| ATLAS_BLACK-NEXON XZ+ DK 1.2 RTN BS6 |
| DAYTONA_GREY-PUNCH ADV 1.2P BS6 MT RT |
| ARCADE_GREY-ALTROZ XZ+ 1.2 RTN BS6 |
| CALGARY_WHTE-NEXON XM(S) 1.2 RTN BS6 |

Here, after using the below query, I got the desired result:

```sql
Select PATINDEX('%-%',PartDesc),Stuff(PartDesc,1,PATINDEX('%-%',PartDesc),'' ),* from #temp
```